# Fortigate Firmware Upgrade

Tags: fortigate

I've two Fortigate 40C here, which are currently running on firmware "Fortigate-40C v4.0,build0639,120906 (MR3 Patch 10)". I want to upgrade to the latest MR3 release, which appears to be MR3 Patch 18.
I logged into my account and downloaded the firmware MR3 Patch 18(Filename: FGT_40C-v400-build0689-FORTINET.out) already.

Fortigate 1 shows "Firmware 8 x 5 support (Expired: 2014-07-20)" in the web interface in the firmware section, Fortigate 2 "8 x 5 support (Expires: 2015-01-22)". I've never upgraded the Fortigate firmware before, so I'm unsure about some things.

1. Fortigate 2, which shows the expiry date "Expires: 2015-01-22", shouldn't have problems to be upgraded to the new version, because it's still in the support contract, but how about Fortigate 1?
   I've already obtained the firmware file, so will it be a problem to upload it to Fortigate 1 and run it or is there a mechanism in place, which will block that?
2. The 40C has 2 partitions. When I upload the new image to partition 2(not active), click "upload" and uncheck "boot the new firmware", it won't affect the running system at all? I just want to upload now and reboot at a later point.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1) You will not have an issue manually upgrading the firmware if you have the file, however, you should renew the support for that unit, as you won't receive signature updates or have access to the FortiGuard services. Also it's ultimately a violation of the licensing agreement, but no one is going to be knocking on your door over it. The reason you are able to download the firmware manually is because you have a unit with an active license on your account, if they were both expired you would be denied download access.

2) You are correct, if you choose to upload to the second partition and not boot, it will simply upload and store it.